# Form Validation and Clearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm a front-end dev new to React. Still trying to figure out the basics. I'm coding an app that requires the user to enter information in a form from a pop-up dialog box. When the box closes I want the form to completely reset/clear and if the data is valid, I want it added to state and displayed in a table.

I've got my form data entry portion working, but I'm currently struggling with clearing the form, and implementing validation. Specifically when the Form closes (cancel button) it needs to clear and reset until the dialog is open again. When the submit buttons is pressed I need to run some kind of form validation to check that each value is entered correctly before being added to state. I don't have anyone senior above me to review my code and provide tips/assistance, so I was hoping someone senior level could point me in the right direction and let me know what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Any other useful tips based on any of my code is welcome.. I know it's probably a bit weird and messy.. I'm sort of learning and building from examples as I go, so forgive my poor/messy code.

Main app.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Form'
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    container: {
      background: 'yellow'
    },
    paper: {
      background: 'red'
    },
    div:{
      background:'black'
    },
    table: {
      width: '100%'
    },
  }
});

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
      dialogOpen: false,
      formClear: true,
      snackBarOpen: false,
      snackBarMessage: 'default meesage',
      tableData: {},
      formData: {
        projectName: '',
        jobNumber: '',
        accountField: {
          selected: [],
          options:[
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'},
            {value: 'test data', label: 'test data'}
          ]
        },
        projectDescription: '',
        designOrDigital: {
          options:[
            {label: 'option A', value: 'optionA'},
            {label: 'option B', value: 'optionB'}
          ],
            value: {}
        },
        mediaDeliverables: [
          {label: 'different', checked: false, quantity:'', details:''},
          {label: 'types', checked: false, quantity:'', details:''},
          {label: 'of', checked: false, quantity:'', details:''},
          {label: 'media', checked: false, quantity:'', details:''},
          {label: 'deliverables', checked: false, quantity:'', details:''},
        ],
        timing: {
          entries : [
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
            {entry: 'Dummy Values', planned:null, actual:null, notes:''},
          ]
        },
        projectMap: {
            selected: null
        }
      }
  }

}

// -----------------
//     SETTERS 
// -----------------

setAccountsSelected = (selected) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.accountField.selected = selected;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setProjectName = (value) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.projectName = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setJobNumber = (value) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.jobNumber = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setProjectDescription = (value) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.projectDescription = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setDesignOrDigital = (value) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.designOrDigital.value = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setMediaDeliverable = (value, index) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.mediaDeliverables[index] = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setTimingData = data => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.timing.entries = data;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setSelectedProjectMapId = data => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formData.projectMap.selected = data;
  this.setState(currentState);
}
setFormClear = (value) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.formClear = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
}


// -----------------
//     HANDLERS 
// -----------------

onDialogOpen = () => this.setState({dialogOpen:true});

onDialogClose = () => this.setState({dialogOpen:false});

onSnackbarClose = (e, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({snackBarOpen:false}); 
  this.setState({snackBarMessage:''});
};

onCreate = () => {

  let theSnackBarMessage = `${this.state.formData.projectName} created`;
  this.setState({snackBarOpen:true});
  this.setState({snackBarMessage:theSnackBarMessage});
  this.onDialogClose();
};

// I was told to use Object.assign to avoid direct mutation of state..
getStateCopy = () => Object.assign({}, this.state); 

render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br /><br /><br />
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.onDialogOpen}>
          Create New Resourcing Request
      </Button>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <div>Table of information will go here</div>
      <Dialog  
        className={classes.root} 
        open={this.state.dialogOpen} 
        onClose={this.onDialogClose}

        maxWidth = {'md'}
        >
      <DialogTitle>Resource Request Form</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <Form 
            projectName={this.state.formData.projectName}
            jobNumber={this.state.formData.jobNumber} 
            accountSelected={this.state.formData.accountField.selected}
            projectDescription={this.state.formData.projectDescription}
            selectedProjectMapId={this.state.formData.projectMap.selected}

            accountFieldOptions={this.state.formData.accountField.options}
            designOrDigital={this.state.formData.designOrDigital}
            mediaDeliverablesOptions={this.state.formData.mediaDeliverables}

            timingData={this.state.formData.timing.entries}

            setAccountsSelected={this.setAccountsSelected}
            setProjectName={this.setProjectName}
            setDesignOrDigital={this.setDesignOrDigital}
            setMediaDeliverable={this.setMediaDeliverable}
            setJobNumber={this.setJobNumber}
            setProjectDescription={this.setProjectDescription}
            setTimingData={this.setTimingData}
            setSelectedProjectMapId={this.setSelectedProjectMapId}
            setFormClear={this.setFormClear}

            dialogOpen = {this.state.dialogOpen}
            formClear = {this.state.formClear}
          />  
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={this.onDialogClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={this.onCreate}
            color="primary"
          >
            Create
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <Snackbar 
          open={this.state.snackBarOpen}
          message={this.state.snackBarMessage}
          onClose={this.onSnackbarClose}
          autoHideDuration={4000}
        />
    </div>
  );

  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
//export default App;
```

The Form.js component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import MediaDeliverablesCheckBox from './MediaDeliverablesCheckBox';
import { default as MaterialRadioGroup } from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import TimingTable from './TimingTable';
import ProjectMap from './ProjectMap';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    width: 1000,
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 370,
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  table: {
    width: '20%',
  }
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

let accountNames = [];

function getStyles(name, accountName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      accountName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label, onMediaDeliverableChange}) => (
    <FormControl>
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
    {values.map((value, index) => (
        <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox
        key={index}
        index={index}
        mediaDeliverablesOptions={value}
        onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange(index)}
      />
      ))}
     </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
);

const CheckboxGroup = ({ values, label, onChange }) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
      {values.map((value, index) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={index}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={value.checked}
              onChange={onChange(index)}
            />
          }
          label={value.label}
        />
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
);

const RadioGroup = ({ value, options, name, label, onChange }) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}

    </FormLabel>
    <MaterialRadioGroup
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      disabled
    >
      {options.map((option, index) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={index}
          control={<Radio />}
          value={option.value}
          label={option.label}
        />
      ))}
    </MaterialRadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
);

export default function Form(props) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const designOrDigital = props.designOrDigital;
  const mediaDeliverablesOptions = props.mediaDeliverablesOptions;
  const accountName = props.accountSelected;
  const projectName = props.projectName;

  accountNames = [...props.accountFieldOptions];

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      //I started experimenting with lifecycle hooks because I thought
      //I might need to clear the form at a certain point in the form
      //lifcycle, but I'm not 100% sure where I need to do this..
      console.log('>> [Form.js] useEffect() = will unmount');
      console.log('>> [Form.js] will unmount: checking if form is closed and clear: dialogOpen=',props.dialogOpen,'formClear=',props.formClear);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => { 
    console.log('>> [Form.js] useEffect() = mounted or updated');
    console.log('>> [Form.js] mounted/updated: checking if form is closed and clear: dialogOpen=',props.dialogOpen,'formClear=',props.formClear);
  });

  const handleAccountChange = (event) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setAccountsSelected(event.target.value);
  }
  const handleProjectNameChange = (event) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setProjectName(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleJobNumberChange = (event) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setJobNumber(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleProjectDescriptionChange = (event) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setProjectDescription(event.target.value);
  };
  const onDesignOrDigitalChange = index => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setDesignOrDigital(value);
  };
  const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => (deliverableData, e) => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setMediaDeliverable(deliverableData, index);
  };
  const timingChangeHandler = data => {
    props.setFormClear(false);
    props.setTimingData(data);
  };

  const clearForm = () => {
    console.log('>> form being cleared');
    //I couldn't figure out how to actually clear the form
    //I experimented with having a boolean value in state to
    //flag that form should be cleared.
    //I attempted to manually clear the form field values via
    //state but it doesn't appear to be working.
    props.setFormClear(true);
    props.setAccountsSelected([]); //pass empty array to clear current array
    props.setProjectName(''); //pass empty string to clear current field.
  }


  console.log('>> [Form.js] (Form) checking if form is closed and clear: ',props.dialogOpen, props.formClear)
  if(props.dialogOpen === false && props.formClear === false) { 
    //I was trying to watch the form state here to tell teh Form component
    //when it needs to clear.. it didn't work so I started experimenting with
    //lifecycle hooks above..
    console.log('>> [Form.js] (Form) Form is Closed');
    clearForm();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="project-name"
        label="Project Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={props.projectName}
        onChange={handleProjectNameChange}
      />
      <br /><br />
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-accounts">Account</InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={accountName}
          onChange={handleAccountChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-accounts" />}
          renderValue={
            selected => (
            <div className={classes.chips}>
              {
                selected.map(value => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {accountNames.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name.label} value={name.label} style={getStyles(name.label, accountName, theme)}>
              {name.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <br /><br />
      <TextField
        id="job-number"
        label="Job #"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={props.jobNumber}
        onChange={handleJobNumberChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <br /><br /><br />
      <TextField
        id="project-description"
        label="Project Description"
        placeholder="Provide a detailed description of the project:"
        className={classes.textField}
        multiline
        variant="outlined"
        value={props.projectDescription}
        onChange={handleProjectDescriptionChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <br /><br /><br />
      <RadioGroup
        label="Please Choose One:"
        options={designOrDigital.options}
        value={designOrDigital.value.value}
        onChange={onDesignOrDigitalChange}
        name="designOrDigitalRadio"
      />
      <br /><br /><br />
      <MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList
        label="Please choose deliverables:"
        onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange}
        values={mediaDeliverablesOptions}
      />  
      <br /><br /><br />
      <TimingTable 
        timingData={props.timingData}
        timingChangeHandler={timingChangeHandler}
      />
      <ProjectMap 
        setSelectedProjectMapId={props.setSelectedProjectMapId}
        selectedProjectMapId={props.selectedProjectMapId}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview) is a fantastic library which handles validation and the minutiae of complex forms for you automatically.  I know it's not much help for this issue, but definitely worth looking into to save a boat load of time on forms down the road.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you're looking for a way to make your code cleaner maintainable, implement validation and logic upon submission.

Forms in ReactJS can get a bit tedious, that's why tools like [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) and [redux & redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/) were introduced.

I personally use Formik for creating forms in react and I think it should be considered as an essential ReactJS package. **And I strongly recommend you to use it unless you have a reasonable justification not to.**

Formik can deal with all form related logic without writing a single line of code, also, **Formik was configured to use [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) which is an npm package for Object Schema Validation for your forms**. Using those tools **WILL** make your life easier

Comment: interesting.. I'm using Material-UI and I put together some custom components to handle sets of checkboxes, etc. Can Formik integrate with those too? Or would I need to recode what I have to work with Formik?

Comment: Of course! I am actually working on a project currently and I am using ReactJS, Material-UI, Formik and Yup. You can use the checkboxes and the text fields from material-ui as inputs to formik. They make a great tech stack! Formik by default works with native html fields but you can integrate anything with it with some slight modifications, Moreover, since you're using Material-UI, this library will do those modifications for you! https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui